# How to deal with super size window in FLINK?

Tags: java-8, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Now I have a requirement that aggregate someone's operations in last 3 month. Then put result into ML model to get anomaly.

Taking into account the huge flow of the system, it's a very big window.

How can I deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question based on the assumption that the data is coming in a streaming fashion and you need to create a window on top of that stream because that detail is not clearly available from your question.

Having said that, you can create a window of such huge size with a RocksDB state backend as the window wouldn't be stored in memory and your window size restriction would depend only on the hard disk size of your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

you can use batch processing for Flink as you have a dataset, however, flink is a true streaming engine, which means batch is considered as a special case for streaming. Another option will be to use Hadoop for this kind of batch processing.